# Any possible side effect to use APC on shared host?

Tags: php, performance, web-server, alternative-php-cache

I'm using a shared host for a CMS site. This shared host has an option to use "APC".

I just tried this option on a test site as it can be enabled just by one click on my account page of the shared host.

It seems that this option speeds up the site. However I'm just worried that it has some kind of side effect that I haven't been aware of yet.

Is there any bad effect that might be cause by enabling "APC" installed a shared host generally?

Answer (score 1):

There's possibly a potential security hole.  PHP APC is an opcode cache, that means that PHP precomputes bits of your script and stores the result in memory.  If your site contained information that you might not want to be public, then there's potentially (depending on the shared host's implementations of both the sharing, and APC) a risk that your cached data might be accessible by users other than  you.

It's all very dependent on how the server's been set up.  I suggest you contact your service provider and ask them.